# Cassandra with c#

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am getting following error while querying the cassandra column family using asp.net csharp. My cassandra version is 1.2.1

> An unhandled exception of type 'Cassandra.ProtocolErrorException'
>   occurred in Cassandra.dll
>
> Additional information: Unknown code 10 for a consistency level

Please suggest the resolution.

Comment: What cassandra driver library and version are you using? From the error message, looks like your client driver and the server protocol mismatches.

Comment: It's CassandraCSharpDriver.3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly specify the protocol version to 1 when creating the cluster instance. v3 of C# driver are quite new while v1.2.1 of cassandra server is very old. Please check this official doc for details:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.0/common/drivers/introduction/driverDependencies_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_a1z_m5f_5j__build-environment-dependencies-section

Comment: I have already done this: 
cluster = Cluster.Builder().WithPort(9042).AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").WithMaxProtocolVersion(1).Build();
            ISession session = cluster.Connect("Demo");

Comment: Before doing any guessing on the V3 of client driver, I'd suggest if you could try to use an older version (V1) of the c# driver first. V1 of the driver usually are tested more with V1 of cassandra server. I've also used V2 of the driver working with both V1 and V2 of cassandra servers well.

Comment: I have downgraded to CassandraCSharpDriver.2.7.0 and the error is now changed to: 
An unhandled exception of type 'Cassandra.InvalidQueryException' occurred in Cassandra.dll

Additional information: unconfigured columnfamily users

where users is my column family. any help?

Comment: In your CQL, are you using KeyspaceName.ColumnFamilyName when specifying columnfamily? Please don't forget the "KeyspaceName." as prefix. Use the following format: INSERT INTO "KeyspaceName"."ColumnFamilyName" (columns) values (values)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the C# driver by default is using LOCAL_ONE consistency level and as Teddy Ma suggests, 1.2.1 is an old release that doesn't support it.

Cassandra 1.2.12 is the first version of C* that supports LOCAL_ONE (0x10 CL).

More discussion recently here on the python list: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/python-driver-user/iBT4W-Ne2y4

> I was curious about this as I had thought C* 1.2 supports LOCAL_ONE.  I turns out LOCAL_ONE was not added until Cassandra 1.2.11, and it was added with the wrong code (0x8 instead of 0x10).  This was fixed by [CASSANDRA-6347](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6347) in 1.2.12.

You can get around this by setting the Consistency Level explicitly on [QueryOptions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.0/html/T_Cassandra_QueryOptions.htm), or by upgrading to a newer version of cassandra (if you have to stay on 1.2, use 1.2.19).